# Use resources folder for VAADIN themes

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I'm trying to build a VAADIN application as an executable jar. I don't want to have a webapp directory for my theme and instead store it in the resource directory.

When running mvn vaadin:compile-theme I get an error indicating that nothing is found in the webapp directory.

Is it possible to switch the directory which Vaadin scans for themes?

Comment: As per the [Vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html) this location seems to be fixed. Also since you'll be running a web application (even with an embedded server), there will be differences in how the resources will be accessed by the web application. When [building the app](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html), maven will output the files under `resources` will in target under `<webAppDirectory>/WEB-INF/classes`, and the web resources under `webapp` will be outputted under `<webAppDirectory>/`.